# C# int64 list to byte array and vice versa casting?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, casting, arraylist

Please show me optimized solutions for castings:

1)

```
    public static byte[] ToBytes(List<Int64> list)
    {
        byte[] bytes = null;

        //todo

        return bytes;
    }
```

2)

```
    public static List<Int64> ToList(byte[] bytes)
    {
        List<Int64> list = null;

        //todo

        return list;
    }
```

It will be very helpful to see versions with minimized copying and/or with unsafe code (if it can be implemented). Ideally, copying of data are do not need at all.

**Update:**

My question is about casting like C++ manner:

```
__int64* ptrInt64 = (__int64*)ptrInt8;
```

and

```
__int8* ptrInt8 = (__int8*)ptrInt64
```

Thank you for help!!!

Comment: do you want to convert each byte into a Int64 (and vice versa) or in chunks of 8 bytes? (sizeof Int64)

Comment: @BrokenGlass i need to cast each 8 bytes (in chunks) to one Int64 value and vice versa;)

Comment: Are you asking for a `BitConverter` solution or a `memcpy` solution?

Comment: @Gabe i am asking ideally for casting if it was on C++: (__int8*)ptrInt64; (__int64*)ptrInt8;

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**, fixed for correct 8 byte conversion, also not terribly efficient when converting back to byte array.

```
    public static List<Int64> ToList(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var list = new List<Int64>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += sizeof(Int64))
            list.Add(BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, i));

        return list;
    }

    public static byte[] ToBytes(List<Int64> list)
    {
      var byteList = list.ConvertAll(new Converter<Int64, byte[]>(Int64Converter));
      List<byte> resultList = new List<byte>();

      byteList.ForEach(x => { resultList.AddRange(x); });
      return resultList.ToArray();
    }

    public static byte[] Int64Converter(Int64 x)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
    }
```

Comment: thank you for help and your code! I need to cast each 8 bytes to one Int64 value and vice versa;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Mono.DataConvert](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_DataConvert).  This library has converters to/from most primitive types, for big-endian, little-endian, and host-order byte ordering.

Answer (score 1):

CLR arrays know their types and sizes so you can't just cast an array of one type to another. However, it is possible to do unsafe casting of value types. For example, here's the source to `BitConverter.GetBytes(long)`:

```
public static unsafe byte[] GetBytes(long value)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
    fixed (byte* numRef = buffer)
    {
        *((long*) numRef) = value;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

You could write this for a list of longs, like this:

```
public static unsafe byte[] GetBytes(IList<long> value)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * value.Count];
    fixed (byte* numRef = buffer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
            *((long*) (numRef + i * 8)) = value[i];
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

And of course it would be easy to go in the opposite direction if this was how you wanted to go.

Comment: Note that this always converts to/from host byte ordering.  If you are using these functions to serialize data or otherwise package it for transport between computers, you should pick a specific byte ordering (big or little endian) and use it exclusively.  Otherwise you will run into trouble when your software is run on a platform with the opposite byte ordering.

Comment: cdhowie: You're absolutely right about the byte ordering, but the OP was asking for how to cast arrays, which implies that he cares only about the host's byte ordering.